# convergence or Divergence of complex Alternating Series

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

> Finding whether the series $$\sum^{\infty}_{k=1}\frac{(-1)^k3^{k}}{k\cdot2^{k}}$$ is Converge or Diverges

What i try: Let $\displaystyle \frac{3}{2}=x$. Then series is $\displaystyle \sum^{\infty}_{k=1}(-1)^k\frac{x^k}{k}=\ln(1+x)-1$

So our sum is $$\sum^{\infty}_{k=1}\frac{(-1)^k3^k}{k\cdot 2^k}=\ln(1+1.5)-1=\ln(2.5)-1$$

So the series is converges.

But answer given as Series is Diverges.

Could some help me to solve it. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The series diverges because$$\lim_{k\to\infty}\left|\frac{(-1)^k3^k}{k2^k}\right|=\infty\ne0.$$

Comment: Thanks Jose Carlos Santos. Is this called Divergence Series Test or Absolute Divergence Test

Comment: I don't know any name for it.

Comment: I've heard this called the $n$-th term test, although this limit is actually a bit harder to justify rigorously than the limit you get from the ratio test, IMO

Comment: Thanks Jose Carlos and Izzak van.

Answer (score 1):

$$ \sum^{\infty}_{k=1}(-1)^k\frac{x^k}{k}=-\ln(1+x)$$ is valid as long as $|x]<1$.

Comment: Thanks so much Peofessor.